# Displaying form data in a message box

Tags: c#, combobox, messagebox

I am trying to display 3 values in a message box when the user clicks Submit as a means to verify correct input.

The 3 values come from comboBoxes in the form: age, height, weight.

In my current set up, the box will only say "age:" with the actual numerical value in the top border.

How can I get the 3 comboBox data items to appear inside a message box with appropriate titles?

Like this:
 Age: 27
 Height: 62
 weight: 180

Data are stored in the variables age_Num.Text, height_Num.Text, and weight_Num.Text

```
MessageBox.Show("Age:", age_Num.Text); //just shows "Age:". Value is in titlebar of mb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must concatenate those values into a single string. Try this, using `StringBuilder`:

```
        StringBuilder MessageText = new StringBuilder();
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Age: {0}", age_Num.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Height: {0}", height_Num.Text));
        MessageText.AppendLine(string.Format("Weight: {0}", weight_Num.Text));
        MessageBox.Show(MessageText.ToString());
```

Comment: Is there a way to display the items with carriage returns after each value so its not one giant string?

Comment: @J.C.Morris Yes, use `MessageText.AppendLine`, it will do the magic. However, the inner string should be modified to `string.Format("... {0} ", ...)`. Got it?

Answer (score 4):

In case of a `ComboBox` you can get the selected text through the [`ComboBox.SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx) property.

To build a string from multiple values you can use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
string age = age_num.SelectedText;
string height = height_Num.SelectedText;
string weight = weight_Num.SelectedText
string text = String.Format(
                     "Age: {0}, Height: {1}, Weight: {2}", age, height, weight);
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use values of combo directly,

```
MessageBox.Show("Sometext 1:" + cbo1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " Sometext 2:" + cbo2.SelectedValue.ToString() + " Sometext 3:" + cbo3.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

or as you already have in variables.

```
MessageBox.Show("Age: " + age_num.Text + " Height: " + age_num.Text + " Sometext 3: " + weight_Num.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like any of the above, simply create a dialog form set up as you want, with static function to show it modally.

Comment: Hmm I never thought about that! Good idea.